# How to add a license text to an open source license plugin?

Tags: android

The [plugin for including Open Source license](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource) text works well, but if I am using fonts with no .jar/.pom and want to include the license text for those fonts, what is the best way to do that using the plugin?

Comment: Since that is a lightly-documented closed-source plugin, my guess is that the simplest solution would be to package those fonts into your own artifact with your own POM that has the license info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought of that as well but wanted to see if someone came up with a solution.

Comment: I tried creating a jar with pom, adding it to the build path/class path, and even referenced it in code, but the plugin does not list it. However, the same jar placed in a maven repository and compiled via gradle is listed.